# What is the bankend program of rand() method in cpp

Tags: c++

Whenever we want to pick a random number from a vector we use a method called rand(). I want to know how it works from the backend.

Comment: If you want to learn the theory about pseudo-random number generation you need to read a lot of math and statistics. If you just want to see some example functions generating pseudo-random numbers then there are quite a few available if you just search a little, including a few standard libraries which are open source.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ["back-end"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends) involved for `rand`.

BTW, in C++ you'll better use [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)  standard header and related utilities, which are in the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library).

The [`rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random)  function is part of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). It is unrelated to C++ vectors.

They (both the `rand` function and utilities from  [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)) are based upon [pseudo-random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), a quite complex field. You can still get a PhD by inventing better PRNGs.

If you want to understand how `rand`  is (or can be) implemented, you'll better study the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C standard library (like e.g. GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)).

If you want to understand how `<random>` is implemented, study the source code of your C++ standard library. If you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. compiling with the `g++` program), it is provided by it.

Answer (score 1):

rand has a seed value - e.g. setting it to the current time...

```
srand( time(NULL ) ); // second good enough
```

Then there is some math such as this....

```
 unsigned int seed; // set by srand
 unsigned int rand() {
    seed = seed * number + offset;
    return seed;
 }
```

The number and offset are chosen, so the whole of the range of `unsigned int are covered.  This generally means some form of prime number.

As mentioned in the comments, this is a very complex area.

If `srand` is not called, then seed has an initial value, which means that (ignoring thread timing issues), your program will get the same results each time it is run.

Getting the same results is handy for re-running tests, but problematic if it is say a game logic.

Comment: "The number and offset are chosen, so the whole of the range of `unsigned int` are covered" - False. The whole range is `0-UINT_MAX`  but `rand()` is only required to cover `0-RAND_MAX`. this may be as low as 32767.

Comment: This (linear congruential generator) is one possible implementation of `rand()`. It's quite common, but neither C nor C++ requires this approach, and some implementations do it differently.